# Options for WYSIWUG Form data entry on web

Tags: .net, pdf, webforms

I'd like to have close to WYSIWYG form entry on the web. Turbo Tax does this. Basically government forms so would like them to be as close as possible to the paper look. Results go to a DB. PDF looks nice but does not seem to give complex validation (if field1 set, enable group input). Fast is always a plus. (IIS, .net).

What options for form entry are available for the web and give positive/negative feedback on it.

Answer (score 2):

You can make a normal form using ASP.Net and use CSS to make it look like a printed form.

Answer (score 0):

Silverlight gives you more control of the appearance than you get with HTML. Online US Tax forms are Silverlight.

Comment: Looks like they use PDF. Can you post a link to where the Silverlight forms are ?